# Silverlight 5 - designing an editor (drag and drop)?

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, editor, silverlight-toolkit

I am currently looking to build a workflow editor in Silverlight that will allow user to drag and drop couple of objects from toolbox and draw them on canvas, connect it with connectors - pretty much like a flow chart designer.

I have gone through Silverlight Toolkit and some other links on the web, but not really sure how would I accomplish this.

1. Is there any built-in functionality in Silverlight, or do I need to use any external libraries for proper drag and drop?
2. How good is Silverlight in drawing custom shapes?

For reference, check "SilverDiagram": http://www.silverdiagram.net/Projects/SilverDiagram.aspx

Appreciate some quick & real help in this regard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.Is there any built-in functionality in Silverlight, or do I need to use any external libraries for proper drag and drop? 
 There is no built in functionality to develop drag and drop in Silverlight. It is always better to develop your own. It is not that difficult.

2.How good is Silverlight in drawing custom shapes?
 Silverlight is your excellent friend in drawing custom shapes. But you need to adapt your thinking you are coming from conventional way of GUI programming like WinForms.